# Interviewing for a new executive position months after starting my current executive position, how do I answer why I am leaving already?

Tags: resignation, job-satisfaction

I left my previous role as an executive of a mid-sized company earlier this year. I left for a variety of reasons and talked through those with my new company. This is a smaller company. They were very excited about my application, and I was very excited about the new role.

Fast forward to now, and it's not as rosey. There were things missed during interview discussions that, while not deal breakers are very large stress inducers for me. I feel it's impacting my ability to effectively lead the teams I was brought in to lead.

I've discussed these with my boss (the CEO) multiple times. It's difficult to tell if they are as concerned about these problems as I am. We've had great conversations on how to work around and through some of the problems. Others have been more shoulder shrugging and met with a "Your problem, you figure it out" attitude.

I've started looking for another role. I've done enough hiring to know that leaving a company 4-6 months after starting doesn't look good and there is a good chance it'll come up in one of the initial calls. Unfortunately, those have not been for high level positions so the answers are probably different than my situation. Not sure though.

How can I adequately answer a variation of "You just started in your current role as an executive, why are you looking to move jobs already?"

I should note that my current company is doing well, so there are currently no risks of layoffs in the current environment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will be tricky to communicate. The reasons you describe are generally acceptable and not much of a problem in most roles. However as an executive it is exactly YOUR JOB to make sure these things don't happen or, if they happen, to manage and resolve them.

So this is a ding on one of your expected core skill. I think your best shot here is to provide and objective analysis of what happened, what you did, what you have learned from the experience and what you will be doing differently in the future so that it doesn't happen again. Demonstrate that you are taking active steps to close this skill gap.

You need to come up with a credible story of why you won't walk out of a new employer after a few months again. That story needs to be carefully tailored to the company you are applying to.

Comment: "However as an executive it is exactly YOUR JOB to make sure these things don't happen or, if they happen, to manage and resolve them" - That's exactly my concern. Thank you for the feedback there. I wasn't sure if it was just something I was concerned about or if it was a real problem.

Comment: First paragraph says it all, that is the difference between executive roles and most other roles at any company.

Answer (score 6):

> Others have been more shoulder shrugging and met with a "Your problem, you figure it out" attitude."

This is not uncommon in small companies. With less staff, the organizational layers and people's roles tend to be much deeper because there's not enough staff to separate everything into neat little responsibilities.

> I feel it's impacting my ability to effectively lead the teams I was brought in to lead.

As small companies tend to rely more on jack-of-all-trade approaches; they tend not to overoptimize their workers, as people with a highly varied tasklist are not as easy to streamline.

You mentioned that *you feel* it impacts your ability to be efficient; but I do want to ask you to evaluate if *the company* feels this way? Because maybe you're expecting the kind of streamlining you see in large enterprises, and your expectations might just be off about that.

Based on the two issues you've pointed out, my gut tells me that you're used to larger companies where roles and efficiency are defined very differently compared to small companies.

---

This is where we reach a crossroads:

If you're looking for jobs in bigger companies, this can give you a reasonable explanation: **a small company environment just wasn't your cup of tea**.

I would offer that it was simply a mismatch, not laying blame on either side of your employment. Put focus on the fact that you felt like you couldn't reach your full potential. This is factually correct (as per your own mention of your efficiency), and comes across positively - assuming you do it without negativity towards your current employer.

If you're looking for jobs in other small companies, I suspect you're going to have to adjust your expectations in regards to "you figure it out" kinds of situations. I can't conclusively judge whether what they expected was truly unreasonable or not, but you're always going to have to be more of a jack-of-all-trades in a smaller company, and I get the feeling that you're either not used to this or not cut out for it (that's up to you to decide).

That's just how it is. Some people thrive on small companies, and others don't. If you don't that's perfectly fine, but then I suggest you steer away from small companies.

Comment: Yeah, can be a pretty big difference between small and large companies in these terms.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I adequately answer a variation of "You just started in your
> current role as an executive, why are you looking to move jobs
> already?"

You answer with the truth. You simply explain why you are looking for a new job.

You make it clear what are stress inducers for you, and what kinds of things prevent you from effectively leading. You do this because it's honest, but also because you want to ensure that the same problems don't happen in your next job.

Obviously, you also want to be prepared to answer why you didn't detect a bad fit while you were interviewing for your current job, and why your next job will be a good fit.

I suspect the answers that you felt were good when you were doing the hiring are very similar to the answers from you that others will find acceptable.